# Need a where clause for an XML Node in a SQL Server 2019 stored procedure

Tags: sql, xml, stored-procedures

I have 1.5 million XML documents stored in a SQL Server 2019 database and I need to have a where clause that has multiple nodes in a stored procedure.

```
<PROJECTS xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <row>
    <APPLICATION_ID>1015</APPLICATION_ID>
    <ORG_STATE>SC</ORG_STATE>
    <ORG_CITY>Charleston</ORG_CITY>
    <ORG_ZIPCODE>29407</ORG_ZIPCODE>
    <PIS>
      <PI>
        <PI_NAME>BO, LEO (contact)</PI_NAME>
        <PI_ID>9983950 (contact)</PI_ID>
      </PI>
      <PI>
        <PI_NAME>KUZ, BEN I</PI_NAME>
        <PI_ID>1862593</PI_ID>
      </PI>
    </PIS>
    <PROJECT_START>08/15/2019</PROJECT_START>
    <PROJECT_END>05/31/2024</PROJECT_END>
    <INDIRECT_COST_AMT>103034</INDIRECT_COST_AMT>
    <TOTAL_COST>638854</TOTAL_COST>
    <TOTAL_COST_SUB_PROJECT />
  </row>
</PROJECTS>
```

I need to pull all XML files where `PI_ID` equals `9983950`. The number of PI's in the PIS node could be one or 5.

I'm using this code:

```
SELECT TOP 100 
    [APPLICATION_ID], [FileName], [XMLData],
    nref.value('ORG_CITY[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)') as ORG_CITY  
FROM
    [NIH_EXPORTER].[dbo].[ADMIN_Exporter_Files_XML] 
CROSS APPLY
    XMLData.nodes('//row[1]') AS R(nref)
WHERE 
    nref.value('ORG_CITY[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)') = 'Charleston'
```

when I need the city but I'm not sure how to find the value when there are multiple nodes

Comment: There's no node with `PI_ID` equals `9983950` in your data . Do you mean  `PI_ID` contains '9983950' ?

Comment: Also, there is no XML element `<ORG_CITY>` in the XML sample.

Comment: The 9983950 may or may not have (contact).  So should contains be always used?

Comment: The <ORG_CITY> has been added back in.  My cut and paste left it out.  XML document is about 100 nodes.  I cut out what was not needed and apparently cut out something that was needed

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, xmldata XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl (xmldata) VALUES
(N'<PROJECTS xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <row>
        <APPLICATION_ID>1015</APPLICATION_ID>
        <ORG_STATE>SC</ORG_STATE>
        <ORG_CITY>Charleston</ORG_CITY>
        <ORG_ZIPCODE>29407</ORG_ZIPCODE>
        <PIS>
            <PI>
                <PI_NAME>BO, LEO (contact)</PI_NAME>
                <PI_ID>9983950 (contact)</PI_ID>
            </PI>
            <PI>
                <PI_NAME>KUZ, BEN I</PI_NAME>
                <PI_ID>1862593</PI_ID>
            </PI>
        </PIS>
        <PROJECT_START>08/15/2019</PROJECT_START>
        <PROJECT_END>05/31/2024</PROJECT_END>
        <INDIRECT_COST_AMT>103034</INDIRECT_COST_AMT>
        <TOTAL_COST>638854</TOTAL_COST>
        <TOTAL_COST_SUB_PROJECT/>
    </row>
</PROJECTS>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @PI_ID VARCHAR(20) = '9983950';

SELECT ID
    , xmldata.value('(/PROJECTS/row/ORG_CITY/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)') as ORG_CITY
FROM @tbl 
WHERE xmldata.exist('/PROJECTS/row/PIS/PI/PI_ID[contains(./text()[1], sql:variable("@PI_ID"))]') = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if any required `PIS/PI` node exists with CROSS APPLY down the chain.

```
SELECT TOP 100 
    [APPLICATION_ID], [FileName], [XMLData],
    nref.value('ORG_CITY[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)') as ORG_CITY  
FROM
    [NIH_EXPORTER].[dbo].[ADMIN_Exporter_Files_XML] 
CROSS APPLY
    XMLData.nodes('//row[1]') AS R(nref)
--
cross apply (select top(1) null x
     from R.nref.nodes('./PIS/PI') t(n)
     where t.n.value('./PI_ID[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)') like '9983950%' ) t
--
WHERE 
    nref.value('ORG_CITY[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)') = 'Charleston'
```